# Wrap weighted Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a parent `LinearLayout` with `weightSum` of value **3** and `orientation="horizontal"` and it has six child `RelativeLayouts` all having width="0dp" and `layout_weight="1"`, so that the last three Relative layouts wrap to next line.  but the first three child relative layouts are showing and the last three are not in the display, I want to wrap them to next line.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/row_wrap"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        >



    <!-- Mileage -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/milage_wrap"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_meter_car"
        android:id="@+id/milage_img"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/milage_img"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/milage_img"
            android:text="32000"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/milage_txt"
            />



    </RelativeLayout>

<!-- transmission-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/transmission_wrap"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/trans_img"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/trans_img"
            android:text="32000"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/trans_txt"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_transmission_car"
            android:id="@+id/trans_img"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>

<!--Engine Size -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/engine_wrap"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_engine"
            android:id="@+id/engine_img"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/engine_img"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/engine_img"
            android:text="32000"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/engine_txt"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

        <!--condition -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/condition_wrap"
           android:layout_weight="1"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_condition"
                android:id="@+id/condition_img"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/condition_img"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/condition_img"
                android:text="Good"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/condition_txt"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- fuel -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fuel_type_wrap"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_fuel"
                android:id="@+id/fuel_type_img"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/fuel_type_img"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fuel_type_img"
                android:text="Diesel"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/fuel_type_txt"

                />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Fuel Consumption-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fuel_cons_wrap"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_fuel_consumption"
                android:id="@+id/fuel_cons_img"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/fuel_cons_img"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fuel_cons_img"
                android:text="13/23"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/fuel_consump_txt"

                />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Edited Note:**
I Dont want to wrap the last three RelativeLayouts in another LinearLayout to move it to next row Because  in case of any empty content of the RelativeLayout I want to set its visibility to `"GONE"` so they may adjust better without leaving empty space.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/row_wrap"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/row_wrap"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="3"
    >

<!-- Mileage -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/milage_wrap"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_meter_car"
    android:id="@+id/milage_img"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/milage_img"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/milage_img"
        android:text="32000"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/milage_txt"
        />



 </RelativeLayout>

  <!-- transmission-->
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/transmission_wrap"
    android:layout_weight="1"

    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/trans_img"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/trans_img"
        android:text="32000"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/trans_txt"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_transmission_car"
        android:id="@+id/trans_img"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


 </RelativeLayout>

 <!--Engine Size -->

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/engine_wrap"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_engine"
        android:id="@+id/engine_img"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/engine_img"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/engine_img"
        android:text="32000"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/engine_txt"
        />

 </RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/row_wrap"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="3"
    >

    <!--condition -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/condition_wrap"
       android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_condition"
            android:id="@+id/condition_img"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/condition_img"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/condition_img"
            android:text="Good"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/condition_txt"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- fuel -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fuel_type_wrap"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fuel"
            android:id="@+id/fuel_type_img"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/fuel_type_img"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fuel_type_img"
            android:text="Diesel"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/fuel_type_txt"

            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Fuel Consumption-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fuel_cons_wrap"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fuel_consumption"
            android:id="@+id/fuel_cons_img"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/fuel_cons_img"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fuel_cons_img"
            android:text="13/23"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/fuel_consump_txt"

            />

    </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but it will show all in 1 row I dont want to show them in one row. just want to wrap the last three elements to next row.

Comment: android:orientation="horizontal please first make it correct

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to have a "wrap" effect of layouts, you should have two nested linear layouts inside your outer layout. Wrapping does not work in Android layouts.

You should have :

```
<LinearLayout orientation = "vertical">
    <LinearLayout orientation = "horizontal" weight_sum="3">
        <Relative layout_weight="1"/>
        <Relative layout_weight="1"/>
        <Relative layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout orientation = "horizontal" weight_sum="3">
        <Relative layout_weight="1"/>
        <Relative layout_weight="1"/>
        <Relative layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Edited the question with a note